# Redirect issues when using MySQL as session storage

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, session, redirect

I have set up a Node.js app where I use sessions and store them in MySQL. When using `MemoryStorage`, redirections work fine, but when using MySQL, `req.session` doesn't update until you reload or you move to a different page, and I'm forced to replace every single `res.redirect('/...')` by `res.render()` of that same page to display anything in `req.session` immediately.

I've tried using both `return res.redirect()` and not, as well as using `setTimeout`, neither work. I can't figure it out and I need sessions to be stored in DB

```
router.get('/student-sign-up', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('student/signUp', {
        title: 'Sign up',
        errors: req.session.errors
    });
    req.session.errors = null; //to flush them on reload
}).post('/student-sign-up', function (req, res, next) {
    //Some form checks
    let errors = req.validationErrors();
    if (errors) {
        req.session.errors = errors;
        req.session.signUpSuccess = false;
        return res.redirect('/student-sign-up');
    }
//...
}
```

The above should redirect to the same page, and display the error (I use Handlebars as my view engine) if there were one, but it simply redirects, and if you refresh manually or submit a faulty from again, then it displays it. Same thing for logins (both success not going into the platform's home, and failure not showing errors either). It's like everything's lagging behind by 1 step...

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the solution. According to the `express-session` docs, all I had to do was force a save and then redirect, as so:

```
req.session.save((err) => {
            if (err) {
                req.locals.error = err;
                return res.redirect('/');
            }
            return res.redirect('/next-section');
        });
```

I'll leave this here for anyone that might have the same issue!